# Three.js:Help for generating a FlowMap

Tags: three.js

I’m trying to generate a flowmap with Three.js: https://threejs.org/examples/#webgl_water_flowmap

I’ve used parts of the code source indicated here: https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/master/examples/webgl_water_flowmap.html but nothing appears on my page: https://flowmaptest-site.superhi.com/

I would be super grateful if someone could help me :slight_smile:

Comment: You gotta check the debugger console.. 
```
water2.js:45 THREE.Water: Required component THREE.Reflector not found.
```
looks like you need to include another component...

Comment: thank you Manthraw and yilmaz! I fixed all the other issues but i can't manage to add the reflector... i added the reflector's code in my sheet but it doesn't work..

Answer (score 2):

The browser console reveals some error messages:

> THREE.Water: Required component THREE.Reflector not found.

`THREE.Reflector` is a dependency of `THREE.Water`. Without including it, the component won't work.

Besides, it seems certain textures can not be loaded from your host.

> GET https://flowmaptest-site.superhi.com/textures/water/Water_1_M_Normal.jpg 404 (Not Found)
>
> GET https://flowmaptest-site.superhi.com/textures/water/Water_2_M_Normal.jpg 404 (Not Found)

Comment: Thank you so much Mugen87! I changed the images and added reflector in my code, in the part where Water is, but Js console is still telling me that THREE.Water: Required component THREE.Reflector not found!!!

Comment: Any idea on how i need to add reflector?

Comment: I don't see in your code where you have included [THREE.Reflector](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/dev/examples/js/objects/Reflector.js). Notice that you also have to include [THREE.Refractor](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/dev/examples/js/objects/Refractor.js). Just do it like in the official example.

Comment: thanks Mugen87! I included the reflector and refractor files but I don't know how i can add it to my flowmap file...

Comment: Here is a fiddle with your fixed code. You camera was too far away from the scene and did not look at the water mesh: https://jsfiddle.net/6ym08593/

Comment: omg! thank you so much Mugen87!!! One last thing though: i've used your code, and the floor appears but not the water animation... https://flowmaptest-site.superhi.com/

Comment: Please upgrade to the latest `three.js` version `R106`.